# Add error bar in each case whitout change de bar value

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Hi**,
-I try make this plot whit error bar in each "Tratamiento" bar. But when I try different shapes the value in the bars change. I tried looking for several examples but couldn't get it done.

```
p<-ggplot(datos,aes(x=proc,y=baerea, fill=trat)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge",) +
  geom_errorbar( aes(x=proc, ymin=mean(baerea)-sd, ymax=mean(baerea)+sd), width=0.4, 
             colour="orange", alpha=0.8, size=0.9,
             position = "dodge",stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FF4141", "#C05700","#005959",
                           "007600", "4B27BF")) +
   labs(title="Title", x="", y="baerea",
        caption="Reference") +
   theme(legend.position = "top",
    legend.background = element_rect(fill="darkgray",
                              size=0.5, linetype="solid", 
                              colour ="black")) 
      p +  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Tratamiento") + theme(panel.background = 
     element_rect(colour = "black"))
```

**PLOT 1**

[image]

-Example

```
library(dplyr)
meandat = datos %>% 
group_by(trat, proc, baerea) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(baerea, na.rm = TRUE), se = sd(baerea))

ggplot(datos,aes(x=proc,y=baerea, fill=trat)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
geom_errorbar(data=meandat,aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se, y = mean), width=0.4, 
             colour="orange", alpha=0.8, size=0.9,
             position = "dodge")+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FF4141", "#C05700","#005959",
                           "007600", "4B27BF")) +
   labs(title="Title", x="", y="baerea",
        caption="Reference") +
 theme(legend.position = "top",
    legend.background = element_rect(fill="darkgray",
                              size=0.5, linetype="solid", 
                              colour ="black"))
```

**PLOT 2**

[image]

-Other example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)

data_summary <- function(data, varname, groupnames){
    require(plyr)
    summary_func <- function(x, col){
        c(mean = mean(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE),
          sd = sd(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))
    }
    data_sum<-ddply(data, groupnames, .fun=summary_func,
                    varname)
    data_sum <- rename(data_sum, c("mean" = varname))
    return(data_sum)
}

df <- data_summary(datos, varname="baerea", 
                    groupnames=c("trat","proc"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(proc), y=baerea, fill=factor(trat))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
             position=position_dodge()) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=baerea-sd, ymax=baerea+sd), width=.2,
                  position=position_dodge(.9))
```

**PLOT 3**

[image]

In this case the values of each bar change if we make a comparison whit **PLOT 1**

Im a little confused.

**Thanks**,

```
Example of data 

datos<-structure(list(baerea = c(0.117, 0.172, 0.241, 0.204, 0.207, 
0.237, 0.158, 0.22, 0.18, 0.131, 0.15, 0.0083, 0.171, 0.164, 
0.031, 0.051, 0.03, 0.027, 0.046, 0.116, 0.142, 0.208, 0.101, 
0.189, 0.206, 0.231, 0.174, 0.154, 0.167, 0.137, 0.0726, 0.146, 
0.141, 0.0171, 0.096, 0.0376, 0.197, 0.174, 0.202, 0.087, 0.163, 
0.066, 0.216, 0.128, 0.222, 0.11, 0.2, 0.097, 0.019, 0.072, 0.073, 
0.272, 0.0373, 0.213, 0.194, 0.152, 0.049, 0.152, 0.135, 0.235, 
0.163, 0.11, 0.121, 0.095, 0.093, 0.167, 0.129, 0.187, 0.202, 
0.028, 0.201, 0.111, 0.147, 0.138, 0.043, 0.162, 0.151, 0.163, 
0.229, 0.107, 0.087, 0.169, 0.142, 0.103, 0.164, 0.277, 0.185
), proc = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", 
"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", 
"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", 
"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", 
"P3"), trat = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T4", "T4", 
"T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", 
"T4", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T3", "T3", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T5", "T5", 
"T5", "T5")), row.names = c(NA, -87L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your last plot looks fine. The difference to your first chart is not that the values change by magic. In the last plot you plot the *mean* by `trat` and `proc`. In your first plot you use the non-summarized data. Here the obs are stacked on top of each other, i.e. plot 1 displays the *sum* by `trat` and `proc`.

Comment: Ok @stefan, Im was a little confused. Im take examples but not see when is `mean` and `sum`. Thanks you.